Can't run php page in RedHat satellite
i'm using RedHat satellite 6.15 in RHEL 8. We want to add some php web page like dokuwiki/racktable there. But i have problem that if i install php and put php files in /var/www/html/pub/ directory, I still get error:
[proxy:warn] [pid 396158:tid 140032213636864] [client x.x.x.x:52599] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /pub/daco.php (scheme 'unix'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule., referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/

in file /etc/httpd/conf.d/05-foreman-ssl.conf there is:
Alias /pub /var/www/html/pub

<Location /pub>
  <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerEnabled off
  </IfModule>
  Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
  Require all granted
</Location>

and
  ProxyPass /pub !

service php-fpm.service running properly. If i turn on debug mode in httpd.conf (LogLevel debug proxy:trace5) i got this logs:
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.419832 2024] [ssl:debug] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] ssl_engine_kernel.c(422): [client x.x.x.x:57334] AH02034: Subsequent (No.2) HTTPS request received for child 16659 (server server.default.com:443), referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.419963 2024] [proxy:trace2] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] mod_proxy.c(690): [client x.x.x.x:57334] AH03461: attempting to match URI path '/pub/daco.php' against prefix '/pulp_ansible/galaxy/' for proxying, referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.419986 2024] [proxy:trace2] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] mod_proxy.c(690): [client x.x.x.x:57334] AH03461: attempting to match URI path '/pub/daco.php' against prefix '/pulp/container/' for proxying, referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.419993 2024] [proxy:trace2] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] mod_proxy.c(690): [client x.x.x.x:57334] AH03461: attempting to match URI path '/pub/daco.php' against prefix '/pulp/assets/' for proxying, referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.419998 2024] [proxy:trace2] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] mod_proxy.c(690): [client x.x.x.x:57334] AH03461: attempting to match URI path '/pub/daco.php' against prefix '/pulp' for proxying, referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.420003 2024] [proxy:trace2] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] mod_proxy.c(690): [client x.x.x.x:57334] AH03461: attempting to match URI path '/pub/daco.php' against prefix '/pub' for proxying, referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.420008 2024] [proxy:trace1] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] mod_proxy.c(743): [client x.x.x.x:57334] AH03463: proxying is explicitly disabled for URI path '/pub/daco.php'; declining, referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.420176 2024] [http2:debug] [pid 406264:tid 140059999020800] h2_session.c(341): [client x.x.x.x:57334] AH03066: h2_session(65,BUSY,1): recv FRAME[SETTINGS[ack=1, stream=0]], frames=3/3 (r/s)
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.420176 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client x.x.x.x:57334] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.420188 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client x.x.x.x:57334] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.420546 2024] [proxy:trace2] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] proxy_util.c(2181): [client x.x.x.x:57334] *: using default reverse proxy worker for unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/pub/daco.php (no keepalive), referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.420579 2024] [proxy:trace2] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] proxy_util.c(2136): [client x.x.x.x:57334] *: rewrite of url due to UDS(/run/php-fpm/www.sock): fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/pub/daco.php (proxy:fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/pub/daco.php), referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.420586 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] mod_proxy.c(1265): [client x.x.x.x:57334] AH01143: Running scheme unix handler (attempt 0), referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.420606 2024] [proxy_http:debug] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] mod_proxy_http.c(1755): [client x.x.x.x:57334] AH01113: HTTP: declining URL fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/pub/daco.php, referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.420640 2024] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(320): [client x.x.x.x:57334] AH02450: declining URL fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/pub/daco.php, referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/
[Fri May 24 14:13:06.420666 2024] [proxy:warn] [pid 406264:tid 140060183660288] [client x.x.x.x:57334] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /pub/daco.php (scheme 'unix'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule., referer: https://x.x.x.x/pub/

Thanks for any hint/help.
PS: Official support told me that, it's not recommended to install any external application on Satellite.
